# executing jar file

Tags: jar, noclassdeffounderror

I'm trying to get my class "lzw.java" deployed as a jar file ,

I made a manifest.txt , compiled and got all .class files ,put the manifest file along with the created .class files , and entered the command

jar -cvmf manifest.txt lzw.jar *.class

a .jar was created , when I double click it , it gives me "Java Exception error has occured",

having tried to execute it through cmd it gave me  " java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

note : the manifest file contains just a "Main-Class: LZW" followed by new line character

Answer (score 1):

Since you use `lzw.java, class` and `LZW` interchanging, I suspect it might be a spelling problem.

*lzw.java* is the source file, not a class. The class should have the name *lzw* in this case.

The class file should be lzw.class - if it is not, the name of your class will be like the file-name without dot-class. Of course you choose the right class name in the manifest file.

Post the whole errormessage, not just parts, if this isn't the source of your problem.

Btw.: I suspect you didn't use a package name for your class? And do you know the convention, to user Uperrcase for class names, which would be Lzw in your case - maybe LZW if it is a well established acronym.

Answer (score 0):

This exception means that the JRE is unable to locate the main Java class you are trying to reach. Make sure you are providing the correct class path when running the command.